# How does amqp_consume_message indicate an unexpected frame

Tags: amqp

The documentation for the function `amqp_consume_message`, for version 0.8.0 of librabbitmq (rabbitmq-c) [says](http://alanxz.github.io/rabbitmq-c/docs/0.8.0/amqp_8h.html#a06ce587aeb171c343f00551580d9438a):

> If ret.reply_type == AMQP_RESPONSE_LIBRARY_EXCEPTION, and ret.library_error == AMQP_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_FRAME, a frame other than AMQP_BASIC_DELIVER_METHOD was received, the caller should call amqp_simple_wait_frame() to read this frame and take appropriate action.

But there is no `AMQP_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_FRAME` error code. So how does the function indicate an unexpected frame?

Comment: I am answering my own question, as is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Since a [commit on 2017-08-02](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/commit/95b62fcb6203fae5cf4f5ea093ea58d2eb95e494) the commentary for that function says:

> If ret.reply_type == AMQP_RESPONSE_LIBRARY_EXCEPTION, and ret.library_error == **AMQP_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_STATE**, a frame other than AMQP_BASIC_DELIVER_METHOD was received, the caller should call amqp_simple_wait_frame() to read this frame and take appropriate action.

So it seems there was an error in that commentary: the error code for an unexpected frame is `AMQP_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_STATE`, not `AMQP_STATUS_UNEXPECTED_FRAME`. Version [`0.9.0`](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/releases/tag/v0.9.0) includes that fix.